# How do I repeat a computation with a decreasing parameter in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following code snippet:

```
import math
n=800
t=380
a=(0.5**t)*(0.5**(n-t))
m=((math.factorial(n))//(math.factorial(n-t)*math.factorial(t)))
a*m  
print(a*m)
```

How do I make it so that it repeats for a decreasing `t`?

Comment: You're not changing t in any way, so it isn't decreasing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to repeat code several times, e.g.

```py
foo = 10
while foo > 0:
    foo -= 1
    print(foo)
```

will output

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: thanks, I have a follow-up question though. How can I add the printed values to a list?

Comment: @yasifrahman: Each time you see `foo -= 1`, you add `items.append(foo)`. Also add `items = []` at the top. However, I strongly recommend asking a new question for follow-ups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop until `t` reaches some value, like this...

```py
#Import math Library

import math

n, t = 800, 380
a = (0.5**t)*(0.5**(n-t))

while t>0:
    m = ((math.factorial(n))//(math.factorial(n-t)*math.factorial(t)))
    t -= 1
    a *= m
```